# spark executor pods creation failed

Tags: apache-spark, kubernetes

Im running spark 2.3.1 on kubernetes 1.11.0

Im getting below error when spark driver pod is trying to bringup executor pods ,it truncates first 7 letters in the pod name and throws error that the name starts with "-"

> io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.KubernetesClientException: Failure
>   executing: POST at:
>   https://kubernetes.default.svc/api/v1/namespaces/mynamespace/pods.
>   Message: Pod
>   "mybrand-sb1-ca-privacy-abc469-38957af1c3393cae8941b0613376040c-exec-29"
>   is invalid: spec.hostname: Invalid value:
>   "-sb1-ca-privacy-abc469-38957af1c3393cae8941b0613376040c-exec-29": a
>   DNS-1123 label must consist of lower case alphanumeric characters or
>   '-', and must start and end with an alphanumeric character (e.g.
>   'my-name',  or '123-abc', regex used for validation is
>   'a-z0-9?').

Comment: Check you are not hitting this bug https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-24894. It seems like the hostname is truncated by executer . Seems to me like more of a Spark issue.

Comment: Looks like `my-brand` is getting chopped from the beginning of the pod name.

Answer (score 0):

the max size of the name is 63 characters. Thats the reason its getting truncated for the first 9 characters. Try to minimize the app name, this will solve the issue.